# Initiating a call using a specific version of TLS

Tags: c#, ssl, httpwebrequest, webrequest, tls1.2

Imagine that I have a web server that support TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.0.

There are 3 clients:

1. Client A only supports TLS 1.0
2. Client B only supports TLS 1.1
3. Client C only supports TLS 1.2

My (admittedly weak) understand around this area is that if the Client initialized a call to the Webserver using their preferred TLS version, then our Webserver will respond using the same TLS version.  Please correct me if I'm wrong here.

However, what I want to do is write a Windows Service that runs on the Webserver.  It generates data and then initializes a WebRequest to a URL on the client and pushes the data to that client.

As an Application Developer, how could I:

- Identify which version of TLS the client supports (may also be SSL here)
- Ensure that my WebRequest connection used that version of TLS

Thanks

FYI: our Application uses .NET 3.5

---

**EDIT**
Just to clarify, the "client" and "server" are all webservers, so really creating a "server-2-server" connection.

Comment: "...initializes a WebRequest to a URL on the client..." This must be either a mistake in your question or in your concept. If you are really trying this TLS versions are the least problem. You then need a _webserver on the client_ with a correct SSL setup.

Comment: @blafasel - you are correct, these are all enterprise webservers.  Server-2-server communication.  Have corrected in main post.